# Close Twitter Bootstrap dropdown popover on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML code:

```
<ul class="inline unstyled">
    <li class="select-value-li dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle select-value" data-placement="bottom">
            -- Select values to show --
            <b class="pull-right caret"></b>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="popover_select_values" style='display:none'>
    <ul class="scrollable-menu unstyled">
        <li>element 1</li>
        <li>element 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(".select-value").popover({
    html: true,
    content: function() {
        return $("#popover_select_values").html();
    }
});
```

I want to close this dropdown when I click anywhere outside it.

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    var isDropdown = $('.select-value-li.dropdown-open').length > 0;
    if (!isDropdown) {
        $('.select-value-li').slideUp();
    }
});
```

This is removing the entire dropdown. I cannot even see the `select-values-to-show` and the caret beside it. I just want to close the popover.

Check out [this JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e46tu6o3/1/).

Comment: Added edit for document.onclick

Comment: You are using popover, not a dropdown. All these dropdown-related attributes in html is just a distraction.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply just call `$(".select-value").popover('hide')` to close your pop over

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I am chasing dropdown when I should be concerned over popover.

Comment: @david This is closing popover even when I click on it.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use `data-trigger="focus"` attribute to auto-hide popover on focus lost. So you don't need to add extra event-handlers.

But it is better to use Dropdowns for this case. Check the link below:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/e46tu6o3/6/

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    var isDropdown = $('.select-value-li.dropdown.open').length > 0;
    if (!isDropdown){
        $('.select-value').popover('hide');
    }
});
```

Please be aware that clicking element 1 or 2 also closes the popover.